# Google mail servers not allowing email setup

Tags: gmail, google

We have a a handful of people helping us configure android phones.  We'll get contracts for 500, 700, 1000 phones for example.

Part of the configuration is setting up a gmail account on each phone.  We started having issues not being able to connect to the Google servers to complete the setup.

Example:

- 5 people setting up phones About 4 - 5 minutes per phone
- Each phone has their own individual Gmail account
- In the email setup section.  We’ll enter the account that is then successfully verified by google as being available.
- Fill out the captcha on the screen submit.
- The following screen states “Couldn’t sign in.  There was a problem communicating with Google servers.  Try again later.”
- When this happens to one - it happens to ALL the phones
- If we move the phones off the building wifi to another wifi say a cell phone hot spot.  And run thru the same procedure on the same phone the email account is completed and set up.

If we come in the next day we just repeat the above.

Our assumption is Google is seeing a large number of accounts being setup from our WAN IP, but we can’t change that ip.  Is there any other work around that anybody can think of?

thank you

Comment: Did you contact Google yet? *http://www.google.com/contact/* , their phone is on that page to the right side.

Comment: Tried calling a few times only get the automated attendant, and was on hold for a couple hours yesterday.  I'm using that as my fall back plan.  Was  hoping for something easier though...:(  Will try calling again today..

Comment: Was able to contact  Google - response was "Gmail is a free service, all tech support documents are online"..

Comment: contact them by email and explain that you need help with business or commercial problem.

Comment: that was done...  To my knowledge no response yet

Comment: Another tech setup a proxy hotspot to spoof our outgoing IP.  I forgot about this.  Something we did while in Europe to watch US tv.  I think this is working, somewhat but I'm not a big fan of this process.